# Python Parent class data access inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Hi I have a problem with accessing data through a child class.

I have a Player class defined like so in Player.py:

```
class Player:
   def __init__(self, thickness):
       from PlayerAnimator import PlayerAnimator
       self.thickness = thickness
       self.isAlive = True
       self.animator = PlayerAnimator(5)
       
   def death(self):
       self.isAlive = False
       self.animator.animateDeath(2)
```

Now PlayerAnimator is defined in separate file called PlayerAnimator.py:
And the reason I'm having it as a child is as following: I want every player in the game to have it's separate animator and that animator needs to be able to access player's data like position, thickness, etc in it's methods

```
from Player import Player

class PlayerAnimator(Player):
    def __init__(self, animationSpeed):
        self.globalAnimationSpeed = animationSpeed

    def animate(self, deathSpeed):
        print(self.thickness)
```

Now when I try to print self.thickness by calling death() inside of some Player's method It says that it doesn't exist. I also tried super().thickness and it also doesn't work.

The point is to have Player instantiated and then as Player is instantiated an animator is being instantied, assigned to Player and it has access to Player's data.
How do I fix this?

Comment: The information is scarce, but this sounds more like case for composition (has a), not inheritance (is a). And it looks like you understand it: _have Player instantiated and then as Player is instantiated an animator is being instantied, assigned to Player_

Comment: but how can PlayerAnimator have access to Player's data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I want every player in the game to have it's separate animator and that animator needs to be able to access player's data like position, thickness, etc in it's methods*.

This is case for composition (`has a` relationship), not inheritance (`is a` relationship). And it looks like you understand it: *have Player instantiated and then as Player is instantiated an animator is being instantied, assigned to Player*

animator.py:

```
class Animator():
    def __init__(self, player, speed):
        self.player = player
        self.global_speed = speed

    def animate(self, speed):
        print(f'Player thickness {self.player.thickness}')
```

Note, it's not clear what Animator.global_speed and `speed` argument of `animate()` would do, but anyway...

player.py:

```
from animator import Animator

class Player:
   def __init__(self, thickness):
       self.thickness = thickness
       self.isAlive = True
       self.animator = Animator(self, 5)
       
   def death(self):
       self.isAlive = False
       self.animator.animate(2)


player = Player(10)
player.death()
```

output:

```
Player thickness 10
```

Given more information it may be possible to have a better approach here or there. And the more I think about it, I hove doubts whether your Player + Animator setup is the best approach.